# Agregar una imagen bitmap de Resources a un pdf con la clase iTextSharp.text

Tags: c#, itextsharp, bitmap

Hay alguna manera de convertir una imagen bitmap que está en mi archivo de recursos a una imagen `iTextSharp.text.Image` para poderla agregar en un pdf?

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.electrans_logo));
```

i me da el siguiente error:

> Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' a 'iTextSharp.text.Image'

He probado varias cosas y sé que hay una solución poniendo una ruta dada pero no quiero depender de una ruta, yo tengo mi bitmap en el archivo recursos y quiero que coga la imagen de ahi y la agregue en un pdf.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548166/how-to-create-a-itextsharp-text-image-object-startng-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: vale gracias @Kiko_L